# puppet how to make puppet to wait for a few seconds

Tags: wait, puppet

I would like to run a webservice and wait for a few seconds after to get the result.

What is the best way to achieve a wait in puppet ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use the linux sleep command with exec and stage it to run after the web-service. something like :

```
exec { 'wait_for_my_web_service' :
  require => Service["my_web_service"],
  command => "sleep 10 && /run/my/command/to/get/results/from/the/web/service",
  path => "/usr/bin:/bin",
}
```

Comment: You may need to use the 'shell' provider as the default posix one does not use the shell.

Answer (score 0):

My take on a local-only wait + configurable retry.

```
define wait_for_port ( $protocol = 'tcp', $retry = 10 ) {
  $port = $title
  exec { "wait-for-port${port}":
    command  => "until fuser ${port}/${protocol}; do i=\$[i+1]; [ \$i -gt ${retry} ] && break || sleep 1; done",
    provider => 'shell',
  }
}

wait_for_port { '3000': }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a class that executes a DSC resource, but required to wait for 20 seconds, before it executes it.
Hence, I used an exec resource, relying on Powershell, just before the dsc resource:

```
$command = 'Start-Sleep -Seconds 20'
exec { 'wait_time':
    command   => $command,
    provider  => powershell,
    timeout   => 0,
    tries     => 3,
    try_sleep => 10
}
```

Of course you can either omit or change the tries and the try_sleep parameters.